# How to hide the referer?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xhtml

I need to link a website from my blog.
I don't want that the owner of that website know that I have linked his website.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://dontknow.me/

i.e.

http://dontknow.me/http://google.com

Comment: That works - David: that is what I meant with my post, just did not choose a proxy from the millions out there in case he wanted to write his own

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to hide this? Anyway it is not up to you to hide - it will be the client that loads your page and click the link.
You would need to use a proxy - something like http://someanonymiser.com/url=http.....

Comment: Your link doesn't work. This isn't an answer, this is a comment

Comment: of course you need to replace "someanonymiser" with the proxy of your choice or the one you write yourself - don't be silly

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to go to that site using window.location

or use a 3rd party service like anonym.to , by just appending the site that you want to link to . For example :

http://anonym.to/?http://www.example.com

Comment: If there's text anywhere in the page, search engines will pick it up eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Put the address in an image and make people type it in.

Comment: I think that putting video (or maybe some pseudo-graphics) with url is more suitable in this case :)

Comment: this won't be very user friendly... a link would be better that hides the referer like the examples above

Comment: The level of user-friendliness will be inversely proportional to the effectiveness of the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do it via Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't keep the referer if the URL was opened with the window.location operation

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.replace('http://www.google.com/')">go to google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.co.cc and sign up for a free domain...
Then set up the domain for Web forwarding. The link on your website will go to your new domain, and then immediately forward to the other guys site... He will be none the wiser, only seeing your domain name you registered at .co.cc

I have tested this will my google analytic account, works a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not 100% what you are looking for, but it could be helpful: [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

Comment: Why would that not send a referrer?